# Boolean Difference makes my object disappear

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to make notches in my hollow pipe-like object. (It has ridges on each end, so it's actually three hollow cylinders that have been '**join**'ed into one.)

When I "**boolean difference**" a cube from my pipe-oid, it disappears.

I'm well aware that **this is a common problem and the culprit is coplanar faces**, so I ensure there are none, *including rotating the objects a fraction of a degree.

No joy.

Anything else I can do? I really hope I don't have to recreate the pipe-oid from scratch and leave it un"**join**"ed for this to work, because pipe-oid actually has eight siblings - all unique sizes.

**My sample file to play with:
https://pasteall.org/blend/b506a504ea9b44c18820b3eb6c06e12d**

[image: Differencing causes my pipe-oid to vasinh]

Comment: Hello, have you tried the Fast solver? Maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The culprit isn't only coplanar faces, but it may be due to incosistent normals, double vertices, internal faces, overlapping edges / faces which can't be merged by distance since their vertices don't share same place in 3d space etc., in fact, all kinds of non-manifold geo. So check both objects for any similar problems

Comment: File link added to opening post, moonboots
I think you're right, Mr.Zak, the object itself probably has flaws.

Comment: Fast solver does not make pipe disappear but doesn't close surfaces to make it solid.

Comment: The problem is that your three cylinders have been joined in a way that creates overlapping faces and that confuses the exact solver.  I think you need to redo the model with only two cylinders attached only at the ends.  You can do all of the stepping up and down of diameters by extruding to the point where you want the step and then extrude-in-place/scale up/down.

Comment: What do you mean "two cylinders only attached at the ends"? Doesn't that make the ends coplanar?

Comment: I don't know what 'self' does, but it worked! I don't know how to set a comment as the answer. Hopefully, the mods will set it straight.

Comment: glad i could help

Comment: @DaveC426913 now that Chris has added an answer, you may [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) his answer as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check self and exact in the boolean modifier.

[image]